# Does the word "comparatively" work fine in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, ielts

Please have a look at this table:

[image]

I have written this overview to describe the table:

> Overall, it can be vividly seen that younger people tend to consume
> less amount of dairy products, while older people consume
> comparatively more. In addition, the 45-65 age group sticks out as
> they consume remarkably more butter than other groups.

In the following sentence is the word "**comparatively**" used correctly? In this sentence I am trying to say that in general, younger people consume less; however, it is not always the case. For instance people between 45 and 65 consume more butter than those older than 65. According to this data, is it correct to say so? I mean does the word "**comparatively**" describes this incompatibility of data correctly?

I want to say that although younger people consume less, there is an exception where 45-65 group consumes less. but I do not want to emphasize this exception, therefore I decided to write it like this. If it is not appropriate, could you please give me a suggestion?

Comment: "Comparatively" is used correctly. "Vividly", "less amount" and "remarkably" are wrong or unnatural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this site does not offer proof-reading of scripts, the following points may be useful.

As "gotube" commented, the word **vividly** is out of place. You mean that it can be **clearly** seen.

We don't talk about **less amount**. **Lesser amounts** or **smaller amounts** would work, so would **a smaller amount**.

You could simply refer to **fewer dairy products** but this might be interpreted as a smaller number of products rather than smaller amounts of such products.

The phrase **sticks out** is uncomfortable in this setting. **Stands out** works well instead.

**Remarkably more** is quite possible. But in a scientific setting **significantly more** might be more appropriate.

And **comparatively** is just fine.

So your revised product might read:

Overall, it can be clearly seen that younger people tend to consume smaller amounts of dairy products, while older people consume comparatively more. In addition, the 45-65 age group stands out as they consume significantly more butter than other groups.

These changes are really concerned with idiom and style-in-context rather than grammar - and are open to challenge as matters of opinion rather than fact.